# project fails to compile when adding a reference of bootstrap.min.cs in .angular-cli.json

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

In Angular project (Using vs code as editor) -
I tried installing bootstrap and was using a reference of

> bootstrap.min.cs file in the .angular-cli.json file in "style"
>   section... "EX: node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.cs "

I do see a node_module folder in my project directory location and it has bootstrap.min.cs file as well.

when I compile the project - I get below error.

```
Failed to compile.

multi ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.cs ./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\<porject path>\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.cs' in 'C:\<project path>'
 @ multi ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.cs ./src/styles.css
```

any clue ? Please advise what I am missing ?

IF I remove the bootstrap reference from `.angular-cli.json` file... application works smooth.

Comment: where you gave the reference?

Comment: shouldn't it be `bootstrap.min.css`?

Comment: Can you show the style section of your .angular-cli.json?

Comment: @Supamiu - You are correct. it should have been .css

Answer (score 0):

Adding bootstrap using angular-cli

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
```